# Querying dates with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, performance, linq, date, linq-to-sql

I have these records in a published date column which are strings. I want to query between the two dates in LINQ to SQL. What is the most appropriate way to query the correct date and leave out invalid dates?

```
published date

 jan
 11-oct
 2010-09-09
 feb
 feb-12
```

The code below solves my problem, but it is highly time consuming for large records and it is not LINQ to SQL.

```
Func<string, DateTime?> tryToGetDate = value =>
{
    DateTime dateValue;
    return DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue) ? (DateTime?)dateValue : null;
};       


var dates = (from bookdetails in bookcategories
             let dateValue = tryToGetDate(bookdetails.PublishedDate)
             where dateValue != null 
             && (DateTime)dateValue >= twomonths 
             && (DateTime)dateValue <= today
             orderby bookdetails.PublishedDate descending, bookdetails.BookId

             select new BookInfo
             {
                 BookId = bookdetails.BookId,
                 BookTitle = bookdetails.Title,
                 Images = bookdetails.ThumbnailImagePath,
                 PublishDate = bookdetails.PublishedDate,
                 AuthorList = bookdetails.BookAuthors.Select(q => q.Author.Author1).ToList(),
                 CategoryList =bookdetails.BookCategories.Select(q=>q.Category.CategoryName).ToList()                             
             }).Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: Better you should go for date columns and from there filter out Day, Month or Year or any combination you need. With string you will face parsing issues...

Comment: i wish i could but the problem is that i can't.

Comment: Why aren't your dates `DateTime`'s within the database?

Comment: well i am fetching it from the google books api and they are having there datetime column as string.

Comment: Even if their data is coming back as a string, surely you could just parse it at the time before inputting into the DB?

Comment: yes that is the thing i am doing now because there's nothing better then having a datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is

```
var dates = (from bookdetails in bookcategories
         where SqlFunctions.IsDate(bookdetails.PublishedDate)==1
         orderby bookdetails.PublishedDate descending, bookdetails.BookId)
         .ToList()
         .Where.(b=> Convert.ToDateTime(b.PublishedDate) >= twomonths 
                 && Convert.ToDateTime(b.PublishedDate) <= today);
```

But if you still want more performance should map the "convert to date" function sql